# Can't render child control which contains repeat items?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am newbiesin webform. I want to render "UserControl1" in a webform page. Then in "UserControl1" i assign a list to its child usercontrol("UserControl2") in which has an "asp:Repeater" template. DOM in "UserControl2" except "asp:Repeater" has rendered.

**Webform Page:**

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        var control1 = (WebUserControl1)Page.LoadControl("~/WebUserControl1.ascx");
        HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter());
        control1.ControlRender();
        control1.RenderControl(htmlwriter);
        string html = htmlwriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

**UseContrl1:**

```
public void ControlRender()
    {
        OnPreRender(null);
    }

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> list=new List<string> {"1", "2", "3"};
        usecontrol2.Products = list;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I find "onPreRender" method in "UserControl2" is not firing, and because i don't want to change the AutoEventWireup value, so i solve it by adding public method in "UserControl2" to call "OnPreRender" manually.Like:

```
public void ControlRender()
{
    OnPreRender(null);
}
```

Any suggestions and opinions are welcome.